# PHP guestbook error

Tags: php, parsing, syntax

```
<?php
    $sql = mysql_connect("localhost" , "root" , "usbw") or die(mysql_error);
    mysql_select_db("guestbook" , $sql);

    if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') (

        $user = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['user']);
        $message = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['message']);

        $query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO message (user,message) VALUES ('$user' , '$message'");
        echo ("Message succesfully added.");
    )
?>

<html>
    <head>
        <title>Guestbook</title>
    </head>
    <form action="index.php" method="post">
        User: <input type="text" name="user"/><br>
        Message: <textarea name="message"></textarea>
        <input type="submit" value="Post!"/>
    </form>
</html>

<?php
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM message ORDER BY id DESC");
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) (

    )
?>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>User:</td>
        <td><?php echo $row['user'] ?></td>
    </tr>
        <td>Message:</td>
        <td><?php echo $row['message'] ?></td>
</table>
<hr />
<?php
)
?>
```

Hey! I'm trying to create a simple php guestbook but I keep getting the following error:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ';' in
>   /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/g_book/index.php on line 7

Can anybody see where I'm going wrong?

Comment: echo the value of `$_POST['user']`.

Comment: Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions to write new code. They are no longer maintained and the community has begun [deprecation process](http://goo.gl/KJveJ). See the [*red box*](http://goo.gl/GPmFd)? Instead you should learn about [prepared statements](http://goo.gl/vn8zQ) and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you can't decide which, [this article](http://goo.gl/3gqF9) will help you. If you pick PDO, [here is good tutorial](http://goo.gl/vFWnC).

Comment: `if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') (` , should be `if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {`

Answer (score 6):

Change () to {...}
here,

```
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {

}


while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {

 }
```

Comment: I can't believe the OP have this wrong

Comment: @AlvinWong, are you new here? :D

Comment: @Adnan :P Now I guess the OP will leave the answer alone and not select an accepted answer

Comment: what i cannot believe is that this answer has 6 upvotes already.

Answer (score 0):

Your "if" statement in line 5 has "(" and ends with a ")" instead of the curly brackets, "{" and "}". The same problem appears in the "while" statement further down.

Answer (score 0):

1-(if) statement in line 5 starts with "(" and ends with  ")" you should use  the curly brackets, "{" , "}". and the "while" has the sam error.
2- you closed the the while statement in line 30 before viewing the data in html table so you want get data viewed , so you should remove the curly brackets in line 30 
the complete right code

```
     <?php
$sql = mysql_connect("localhost" , "root" , "usbw") or die(mysql_error);
mysql_select_db("guestbook" , $sql);

if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {

    $user = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['user']);
    $message = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['message']);

    $query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO message (user,message) VALUES ('$user' ,    '$message'");
     echo ("Message succesfully added.");
}
   ?>

  <html>
   <head>
    <title>Guestbook</title>
</head>
<form action="index.php" method="post">
    User: <input type="text" name="user"/><br>
    Message: <textarea name="message"></textarea>
    <input type="submit" value="Post!"/>
 </form>
</html>

  <?php
 $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM message ORDER BY id DESC");
 while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {


   ?>
   <table>
   <tr>
       <td>User:</td>
       <td><?php echo $row['user'] ?></td>
  </tr>
    <td>Message:</td>
    <td><?php echo $row['message'] ?></td>
  </table>
    <hr />
 <?php
}
  ?>
```